# Symfony 5, form error Twig\Environment::getTemplateClass()

Tags: forms, symfony5

I'm trying to create a registration form and add the form to the template for documentation

Controller:

```
class RegController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
    {
        $user = new Admin();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);

        return $this->render('registration/reg.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Form type:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Admin::class,
        ]);
    }
```

}

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ 'Register' | trans }}!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <main class="form-signin admin-register" style="max-width: 300px">
        {{ form(form) }}
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Error:

```
Twig\Environment::getTemplateClass(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given
```

Question:

It seems to have done everything according to the documentation, why can the following error occur?

Comment: Do you have a `base.html.twig` template that exists?

Comment: Yes, if I delete the form, then everything works